# Why doesn't $[a]^{[b]} = [a^b]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, integers

When we construct the modular numbers $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ so that addition works as $[a]+[b]=[a+b]$ and multiplication works as $[a][b]=[ab]$, we get for free that $a[b]=[ab]$ also works.  Why can't we also define a sense of exponentiation $[a]^{[b]}$ as $[a^b]$?  We *do* have that $[a]^b = [a^b]$ because $$[a]^b = [a]\cdots [a] = [a\cdots a] = [a^b]$$ but what is different about exponentiation vs addition and multiplication that we can't define $[a]^{[b]} = [a^b]$?

Example where the formula doesn't work: Let our modular system be $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$, then $$[5]=[1], \text{ but} \\ [2]^{[5]} = [2^5] = [0] \ne [2] = [2^1] = [2]^{[1]}$$

I'm looking for an intuitive explanation as to why this doesn't work right when the similar formulas for $+$ and $\cdot$ do.

Comment: @infinitylord, hm?

Comment: Rather: why would it hold? Your question is weird... There is no reason to expect things will work "as expected" — at most, one should be asking why it does work in the few cases where it does work.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Maybe I'm misunderstanding his notation. It makes no sense to me how $[ab] = [a][b] \implies [ab] = a[b] $

Comment: @infinitylord Using $[x]+[y]=[x+y]$ and associativity, we have $$a[b] = \underbrace{[b]+\cdots +[b]}_{a\text{ times}} = [\underbrace{b+\cdots + b}_{a\text{ times}}] = [ab]$$

Comment: @Dylan: That makes sense, nevermind then. The notation just irritates me, since I feel that all numbers involved in a modular calculation should be modular.

Comment: @infinitylord Well I had to use some notation to distinguish repeated addition from multiplication of modular numbers.  And I've seen this notation used before.

Comment: The problem is that $[a]^{[b]} = [a^b]$ is not well-defined. The reason is that we need $b = c \pmod n$ to imply $a^b = a^c \pmod n$. But the sequence $a^x \pmod n$ has period dividing $\phi(n)$. And it is possible for $b = c \pmod n$ without $b - c$ dividing $\phi(n)$. The congruence class of $[b]$ in the exponent will need to be taken from $\mathbb{Z}/\phi(n)\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It's possible for $[a^b]\ne [a^c]$ even if $[b]=[c]$.

Comment: @TobErnack  if $gcd(a,n) = 1$. Otherwise the sequence $\{a^x \bmod n\}_{x \in \mathbb{N}}$ only ends being periodic with a period dividing $\phi(n)$  (for example take $n = a^3$)

Comment: Yes, what I should have really said is that if $\gcd(a, n) = 1$ then the period of $a^x \pmod n$ is a divisor of $\phi(n)$ called the order of $a$. And it would be possible for $b - c$ to be divisible by $n$ without being divisible by the order of $a$, for example if $b - c = n$ and $\gcd(n, \phi(n)) = 1$. (By the way, I think the period divides $\phi(n)$ even if $\gcd(a, n) \neq 1$ but I could be wrong).

Comment: In general, exponentiation is not very analogous to addition and multiplication.  For example, exponentiation is not associative or commutative.

Comment: "what is different about exponentiation vs addition and multiplication that we can't define [a][b]=[ab]"  If $n|a$ then $n|ka$ if $n|a$ and $n|b$ then $n|a+b$.  If $n|b$ and $n\not |a$ then $n \not |a^b$.  In exponentiation Divisibility and remainders are determined entirely by the base and not at all by the power.

Comment: @TobErnack In general $\{a^x\bmod n\}_{x \in \mathbb{N}}$ isn't periodic for every $a$. But there is a $m$ such that $\{a^{x+m}\bmod n\}_{x \in \mathbb{N}}$ is $\phi(n)$-periodic. Proof : this is true if $gcd(a,n)=1$. Otherwise take $p$ a prime divisor of $n$. Let $l$ such that $p \nmid \frac{n}{p^l}$. Thus $p^{\phi(\frac{n}{p^l})} -1 \equiv 0 \bmod \frac{n}{p^l}$ and since $\phi(n) = \phi(p^l)\phi(\frac{n}{p^l})$ : $p^{\phi(n)} -1 \equiv 0 \bmod \frac{n}{p^l}$, hence $p^{m+\phi(n)} -p^m \equiv 0 \bmod n $ for every $m \ge l$. Finally factorize $a$ in prime factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arithmetic $\mod n$ is determined by the divisibility of classes and the resulting remainders.   An exponential power will not in any way be divided by nor have any remainder in terms of $n$.

Example:  $15^6$ means we multiply $15$ by itself $6$ times.  $3|15$ is important and so $3|15^6$.  That $3|6$ is completely irrelevant.  We are not doing *any* arithmetic operation *ON* the $6$. The $6$ only tells us how many times we are doing an operation *on something else*.  The $6$ is not being acted open in any way.

So $15^6 \mod 7 \equiv (2*7 + 1)^6 \mod 7 \equiv 1 \mod 7$ but nowhere in the equation do we have any arithmetic activity happening *to* the $6$.

Comment: I'm not exactly buying this argument. 15*6 means 15 + 15 + 15 + 15 +15 + 15, so 6 times, so by analogy we're not doing any arithmetic operation _ON_ the 6.

Comment: So by your analogy what is the addition equivalence of $3|15$ that would fail?  $3|15$ IS about grouping 15 into 3 equal groups for adding so if we can group 6 units of 15 the six is important.  but $3|15$ is not about groups of mulitplication.  Because if you have $a|k$ then $a|k*M$ for *any* M.  But if you have $a|k$ it doesn't follow you have $a|k + M$ for every $M$.

Answer (score 3):

The key notion here is a *congruence* — "congruent modulo $n$" was constructed to be an equivalence relation that respects addition and multiplication, but need not preserve anything not constructed from them.

So, it's not really about addition/multiplication being special at all — it's about the relation being constructed.

As an example consider instead the rational numbers modulo $1$; that is, $p \equiv q$ if and only if $p-q$ is an integer. This is a congruence for addition: $[p+q]=[p'+q]$ whenever $[p] = [p']$, but it can't be such for multiplication: e.g. $[1/2] = [3/2]$, but $[1/2 \cdot 1/2] \not\equiv [3/2 \cdot 1/2]$.

Similarly, we could consider the equivalence relation on the integers defined by $x \equiv y$ if and only if either $x$ and $y$ are both zero or $xy$ is a nonzero square. This equivalence relation is a congruence for multiplication: $[xy]=[x'y]$ whenever $[x]=[x']$, but it can't possibly respect addition: $[1] \equiv [4]$, but $[1+1] \not\equiv [1+4]$

---

A note on language: normally the kind of structure is implicit, and we just speak of congruences. e.g. if we're talking about rings, then we simply say "congruence relation" for an equivalence relation that respects addition, negation, and multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

$$[a]^{[b]} \overset{?}{=} [a^b]$$

It's not uncommon to assume properties about a certain notation that aren't true. For example, $\sqrt{a+b} \ne \sqrt a + \sqrt b$. I've always found that plugging in numbers and observing the results is helpful.

It is true that
$$[13^{15}] = [3]^{15}= [3]^{5} \cdot [3]^{10}$$

If this is going to equal $$[13]^{[15]} = [3]^{[5]}$$

then we are going to have to require that 
$$[3]^{10} = [1]\; \text{instead of}\; [9]$$

### one more try

It isn't hard to show that $[a^b] = [a]^b$. So you could rephrase your question as

> Why isn't $[a]^b = [a]^{[b]}?$

If the domain is $\mathbb Z_B$, then there exists a positive integer, $\beta$, such that $b = [b] + \beta B$ where $0 \le [b] < B$.

Then $[a]^b = [a]^{[b]+\beta B} = [a]^{[b]} \cdot [a]^{\beta B}$

So, in order to have $[a]^b = [a]^{[b]}$, it must be true that $[a]^{\beta B} = 1$. Since $\beta$ is basically arbitrary, we really must have $[a]^B = 1$. This is usually not true.

Comment: That does show that *something* is very wrong but it doesn't show what.  Of course our problem in showing what is wrong is trying to explain that *nothing* is right.  There no reason the statement *should* be true so its hard to explain why it isn't.

Answer (score -1):

You might like [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem). It says that when $a$ and $n$ are coprime, we have $a^{\varphi(n)}\equiv_n1$. Taking your bracket notation and adding a subscript to indicate which modular group we're talking about, this means that $[a^b]_n=[a]_n^{[b]_{\varphi(n)}}$ (again, whenever $a$ and $n$ are coprime). So, we *can* do modular arithmetic on exponents in many cases -- it just isn't necessarily modular with respect to $n$!

This certainly doesn't show that arithmetic modulo $n$ on the exponent definitely can't work, but it can be treated as a clue:
there's no reason to believe that $\varphi(n)$ is a factor of $n$, or that just because arithmetic mod $\varphi(n)$ works therefore arithmetic on the greatest common divisor of $\varphi(n)$ and $n$ works.